# Set user agent in codeception cept

Tags: php, testing, codeception

I have some features / limitations in project for search bot crawlers and I would like to test them using codeception and I found there is an option to set headers using `setHeader` method. In my case it doesn't work though. I'm getting `[RuntimeException] Call to undefined method FunctionalTester::setHeader` error.

Code bellow:

```
<?php
/** @var \Codeception\Scenario $scenario */
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);

$I->setHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)');

FileDetailPage::of($I)->amOnFileDetail(96972088, 'raped.zip');
```

According to [Authorization header not making it through in Codeception API testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055181/authorization-header-not-making-it-through-in-codeception-api-testing) I wonder if I have to set user agent header for every request. Isn't there method or configuration option to change **User-Agent** permanently?

Comment: setHeader method only works with PhpBrowser module, have you enabled it?

Comment: I'm using module based on phpbrowser but it probrably doesn't support setting headers as I can see. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be confusing *Functional tests* with *Acceptance tests*. Only Acceptance tests use `PhpBrowser`. Functional tests run the PHP code directly without making HTTP requests.

But to try to answer the question of setting headers globally...

Based on my understanding of the [doc page here](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#Configuration), I *think* you're supposed to be able to set the user agent in your config file, like this:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://ames.dev/
            headers:
                User-Agent: Codeception Custom User Agent
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

But I haven't got this fully working yet. Please assist by editing my post if you'd like to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I made it work like this:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://xxxx.xx
            headers:
                header-testing:
                    value: someValue
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

This makes array value in the `$_SERVER` variable:

```
HTTP_HEADER_TESTING => "someValue"
```